# Java Class Corrupted in Android Studio

Tags: java, android-studio

.java class is displaying this code. I have checked the root url . There is nothing in there . I am not able to find my java code and there is nothing in VCS-> Local History and as proguard is enabled i am not able to get my code from classes.dex

```
<component name="libraryTable">
    <library name="android-mail-1.5.5">
    <CLASSES>
    <root url="jar://$USER_HOME$/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/com.sun.mail/android-mail/1.5.5/53a2f927b235acb565dbe9314ececfb7e6d43020/android-mail-1.5.5.jar!/"/>
    </CLASSES>
    <JAVADOC />
    <SOURCES>
    <root url="jar://$USER_HOME$/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/com.sun.mail/android-mail/1.5.5/3bc78121c0f32347049349f999ca9a3039f6d64e/android-mail-1.5.5-sources.jar!/"/>
    </SOURCES>
    </library>
    </component>
```

Comment: so you have a corrupted obfuscated jar and you want to recover source code?

Comment: Yes Could you help me please

Comment: sorry i can't help, just wanted to make ur question clear for others